# Unable to find Word and PowerPoint in start menu seach

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-word, microsoft-office, microsoft-powerpoint, start-menu

I've recently got a new computer, and was tasked with some basic configuration.

I've created 4 accounts, all of them administrators.

On one of them, I've created taskbar and desktop shortcuts for Word and PowerPoint.

When I tried to do so on the second account, I've successfully got to the Word and PowerPoint shortcuts via the start menu search, but when I placed them on the desktop: their icons disappeared (they weren't actually gone, but the images were replaced by the default icon which appears when Windows cannot find some image).

On the third account, I couldn't even find Word nor PowerPoint. I can, however, find the rest of Office (Outlook etc). But Word and PowerPoint seem to be gone.

Why is this happening? How can I fix this?

And it is a genuine Windows copy, but I wasn't the one who installed it.

The OS is Windows 7 Professional.

*Note: I can still actually use the programs if I navigate to them manually (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office12).*

*Note: The original account still has the shortcuts and is able to find them.*

Comment: How did you create the shortcuts?

Comment: 1. Open the start menu, 2. Type in "Word", the program appears as the first result, click and drag onto the desktop. I thought that I might have deleted the shortcut by doing that, but no, when I search for it on the initial account, it's still there.

Comment: All of the accounts are new?  I've often found that broken file associations for system files (.lnk, .exe, etc) are due to corrupt profiles.

Comment: @Josh, actually no. There was a preinstallation on the PC, with one account (the one on which everything works) as an administrator. I've added three new ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the property of the source icon being copied to the desktop.

Is the shortcut a file ending in .lnk? ( hidden suffix must be enabled in explorer)

Is it a GUID #  like {WXYYZZZZ-6000-11D3-8CFE-0050048383C9} ?  << MOST LIKELY <<<

The desktop properties are defined in desktop.ini and also the GUID may not be registered { in the registry}

The fact about win7 registration is irrelevant

Is MS Office Registered and installed correctly?

The best way to create a shortcut to the desktop from the executeable files or the .lnk shortcuts GUID have special properties which may be included in desktop.ini but requires more explanation.

e.g. "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office10\Shortcut Bar\Office"

- Select with mouse the above quoted folder ((ctrl+v)
- Copy the above including quotes
- Press on kbd.  Win+R (run) >> Ctrl+v (paste)
- and change 10 to the relevant number of Office installed e.g. 11, 12....
- {enter}
- select one or more applications with mouse (Ctrl+ left click) in Shortcut bar folder
- press right click {Alternative click}
- choose > Sendto> desktop  {left click}

DONE

Comment: This isn't actually an answer, it should be a comment. (Also it's very hard to read due to a complete lack of punctuation in the first paragraph.)

Comment: And to answer your question: I have no idea. They actually seem to be taskbar shortcuts, as I can no longer see them on the desktop. And Windows doesn't allow me to inspect those. Neither does it allow me to navigate to the shortcut's supposed location: the shell says the directory isn't there and the Explorer doesn't see it either.